# How to make JS and CSS cacheable until changes?

Tags: javascript, php, css, apache, caching

How to make JS files and CSS files cacheable, until the files are changed? I'm using HTML, JS, CSS, PHP on a apache server. The PHP page must not be cached. Thanks in advance!

EDIT: what Google PageSpeed Insights says:
[image: Google PageSpeed Insights]

Comment: As far as I am aware they will be cached by the browser automatically, assuming you are talking about cacheing in the browser

Comment: But Google PageSpeed insights says that I have to make my JS and CSS cacheable by setting a expiration date.

Comment: There must be 1000 articles on this subject here is one in the **Google Page Speed Help** https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/http-caching#defining-optimal-cache-control-policy

Comment: @blobliebla this isn't a code-writing service, do some actual research.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I did, but I don't understand it properly. That's why I'm asking this question on StackOverflow.

Comment: _I did, but I don't understand it properly_.^^^ **Thats what TESTING is for, to improve understanding**

Comment: Then you should be able to **be more specific** - *"I've tried X but it didn't work because Y and I don't get what line Z is supposed to be doing"*. Give a [mcve] and demonstrate you've put some effort in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For php set in php file put `expiration date` in header very big

```
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); // HTTP/1.1
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 2020 05:00:00 GMT"); // 2020
```

OR past date

```
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1999 05:00:00 GMT"); // 1999
```

To say to browser to reload cached pages you cau change header to somethink like this

```
 header ("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); 
 header ("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT"); 
 header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); header("Pragma: no-cache");
```

htaccess rules to disable cache

```
 <filesMatch "\.(html|htm|js|css)$">
 FileETag None
 <ifModule mod_headers.c>
  Header unset ETag
  Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
  Header set Pragma "no-cache"
  Header set Expires "Mon, 26 Jul 1999 05:00:00 GMT"
  </ifModule>
  </filesMatch>
```

Comment: But what if I set the expiration date to one week, and I change my code before the expiration date?

Comment: @blobliebla look up *"cache busting"*

Comment: can you please translate this to .htaccess "code/rules"?

Comment: Thanks for the htaccess rules!

Comment: Are the files now forever cached until they change?

Comment: No. Nothing lives forever. One, because user can change browser or clear it by deleting cache and coockies

Comment: But if the user don't delete them and don't switch to another browser, are they cached forever then?

Comment: Browser usually reserves certain amount of disk for cache, and if emty space end I think it delete cache